# mock for call who receive list and return a string

Tags: junit, mocking

I would do a mock for a call inside a function who receive a list and return a String. I tried follow several webs but i can not understan how adapt the code for my case. I have this code to mock:

```
public class Procesa {
 public String preparaComando (List <String> comando){
        Prepara prepara = new Prepara();
        List <String> comandoCodificado = new ArrayList<String>();
        comandoCodificado = prepara.preparaTexto(comando);

        String textoRetorno = "";
        for (String cadena : comando)
            textoRetorno+= cadena + " ";

        return textoRetorno;
    }
....
}
```

And I tried do this test:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ProcesaTest {

    @Mock
    Procesa procesa = mock(Procesa.class);
    @Mock
    Prepara preparaCom = mock(Prepara.class);
....
    @Test
    public void TestPreparaComando() {
        List lista = new ArrayList<>();
        lista.add("encenderluzcocina");

        verify(procesa).preparaComando(anyList()).contains("encender");
        assertEquals("encenderluzcocina", procesa.preparaComando(anyList()));

    }
}
```

How can I test this function?

Comment: And side note: English is the primary language on this site. So, instead of posting code that is Italian?Spanish? ... better prepare a **minimal** example that shows your problem using **English** terms. That simply increases your chances of receiving helpful answers.

Comment: Just wondering: what is the point of de-accepting one month after the question, without accepting **another** answer? Chances for you to receive any other new answer here are very close to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **not** use **any** mocking to test such code. Your method receives a list of strings; and it returns a string. That should be all that matters.

In other words: your method has a certain contract: given input X, it should deliver output Y. How that method comes from X to Y - that goes under **implementation details**. And you do **not** test implementation details.

So, in short, the answer is: you step back, and figure the complete set of  meaningful input values { X1, X2, ..., Xn }. Then you determine which output values { Y1, Y2, ... Yn } correspond to each input. Now you write n tests; one for each pair Xi, Yi.

[hint: it might also be a valid "Yi" to expect a certain exception to be thrown; instead of a value being returned ]

Long story shorts: if your method has such a nice input/output setup; then you should **only** test it using asserts. If your method works by changing **other** things within your class under test; then consider adding getters that allow you to inspect that state.

And if mocking is required, then you should use **dependency injection** in order to provide a "mocked" thingy into your class under test.

Finally: if you are interested in learning how to write testable code, watch these [videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLD0011D00849E1B79)!

Comment: Thank you very much!!! I solved my problem and I have learned more about the process of testing. You have provide me an excellent response, thank you!!

Comment: You are very welcome; always glad to help; and such nice feedback is a good completion for a long week!

Comment: This answer is assuming that a *black box* test is possible and viable. Ok, if that is indeed the case, then I would totally agree it should be written as such, without any mocking. However, if it turns out that the `Prepara` dependency gets in the way (maybe it calls a remote web service, for example), *then* it would be just as valid to write a *white box* test where this dependency is mocked.

Answer (score 1):

Just to complement the other answer, we could also write a so-called *white box* test (also known as an "isolated unit test") where the `Prepara` dependency is mocked.

For example, the following test could be written (using the JMockit mocking library here, others could be used as well):

```
public class ProcesaTest
{
    @Tested Procesa procesa;
    @Mocked Prepara preparaCom;

    @Test
    public void preparaComando() {
        final List<String> comando = asList("a", "b", "c");

        new Expectations() {{
            preparaCom.preparaTexto(comando); returns("encender", "luzcocina");
        }};

        String result = procesa.preparaComando(comando);

        assertEquals("encender luzcocina", result);
    }
}
```

This said, though, a black box test is almost always better than a white box test.